# Options if a nuget package hasn't been updated

Tags: visual-studio-2010, jqgrid, nuget, nuget-package

We use jQgrid in many in many of our apps and nuget would be the perfect way to ensure that we keep up to date with the latest version but if the author of the nuget package doesn't keep it up to date then it makes more sense for us to manually keep it up to date.

JQGrid is on v4.4.0 while the only useable nuget package is on v4.2.0 (last updated Nov 2011). There are some specific fixes in the new version that I want to upgrade for.

http://www.trirand.com/blog/

http://nuget.org/packages/jquery.jqgrid

Is there anything I can do if the author of a nuget package has stopped updating it?
Is there a way to recommend that the package gets taken over, removed or a new one created from scratch?

**Update**

I tried to contact the owner to ask him to update it but unfortunately didn't get an answer. I would create a nuget package myself (with multiple owners) but all the good names for jqGrid have been taken too so unfortunately I think I'm going to have to avoid nuget for jqGrid and go back to updating it manually :(

Comment: Perhaps the [NuGet discussion area](http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/topics/5362/general) is a more appropriate place to ask this question.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek yeah I couldn't make up my mind if it was suitable for stackoverflow or not - will leave it up here for now in any case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to take over maintaining it, you can contact the owner and ask to be made into an "Owner".  I was in a similar situation before, but then the current owner got to be much more regular in keeping the NuGet package up to date.  I never got around to requesting permission in that case.

In other cases I've had packages that I wanted on NuGet that weren't mine so I just put them up there (license allowing, of course).  In those cases I email the author and let them know that I'm willing to transfer ownership if they want.  They usually thank me for putting it up there and then do *not* ask to take over the package.  So far I haven't seen any cases of "jealous owners".  Most are happy to have someone else take on the task.

There doesn't appear to be any standard way of suggesting that a NuGet Owner be evicted.  As for starting one from scratch, that's entirely possible if you use a different package ID.  However, keep in mind that NuGet packages cannot be deleted from NuGet.org, only unlisted.  So, it might be a better idea to post your "unofficial" version on an alternate host like MyGet.org.

Comment: Thanks Jim, I'll try and contact the owner - I hope the nuget site has some kind of messaging feature

Comment: Just found the contact owners link :)

Comment: I tried to contact the owner to ask him to update it but unfortunately didn't get an answer. I would create a nuget package myself (with multiple owners) but all the good names for jqGrid have been taken too so unfortunately I think I'm going to have to avoid nuget for jqGrid and go back to updating it manually.